# How to specify key param order using Spring Data Mongo Mapper and composite key

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a POJO that i would like to persist using a composite key to support multi region mongo distribution using where sharding is done first on region then on object id. To facilitate this, I created the following POJO:

```
@Document("users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Key id;
    ... // other irrelevant fields + getters/setters
}
```

The Key class looks like this:

```
// Note the order of fields is region, then id
public class Key implements Serializable {
    private final @NotNull String region;
    private final @NotNull String id;
    public Key(@NotNull String region, @NotNull String id) {
        this.region = region;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when the Spring Data mapper converts this to a document it results in the following:

```
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "12345", "region" : "us_west" } }
```

when I was expecting this (crucial due to db sharding):

```
{ "_id" : { "region" : "us_west", "_id" : "12345" } }
```

One thing i observed is that the mapper seems to convert any Java fields titled "id" to "_id" and automatically move them to be first. This is precisely what i would like to prevent if possible. One workaround that i have found was to rename the second part of my key to "id2" like so:

```
public class Key implements Serializable {
    private final @NotNull String region;
    private final @NotNull String id2;
    public Key(@NotNull String region, @NotNull String id2) {
        this.region = region;
        this.id2 = id2;
    }
}
```

This gave me a workable solution with the result of:

```
{ "_id" : { "region" : "us_west", "id2" : "12345" } }
```

... however ideally i don't want to have to rename the fields as it impacts other areas of my code so I was wondering if there was a way to specify order of fields to the mapper with an annotation perhaps or to enforce POJO declaration order which is what i expected to happen in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the `@Field` annotation did what i needed. In this case simply using the `order` argument was not enough because since the Mongo mapper renamed `id` to `_id` it also placed that property first. Once I added the explicit persistence value argument to be `id` then everything worked as intended.

```
public class Key implements Serializable {
    @Field(order = 1)
    private final @NotNull String region;
    @Field(value = "id", order = 2)
    private final @NotNull String id;
    public Key(@NotNull String region, @NotNull String id) {
        this.region = region;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And here was the persisted mongo document:

```
{ "_id" : { "region" : "us_west", "id" : "12345" } }
```